# How to Customize No shipping method available in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I would like to add a different error message and ask the customer to contact us for a quote If no shipping method is available, how can I customize this option, please check attached image and if anyone can guide how to achieve this.

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick way you can change in translation file : app/design/frontend///i18n/en_US.csv.

Add translation into en_US.csv

Another way you can override by below file and search and change message

```
vendor/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<package>/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html
```